Can you sell all of your Monopoly properties to one other player for $1?
If a player has a feeling they are not going to win, but they want to quit, and they ask another player if they want to buy all of their properties for $1, is that cheating or not allowed?

This is generally considered bad sportsmanship at least.

It is not cheating. Players are allowed to sell properties to other players. The usual rules (selling off all the improvements to the bank first) still apply.
Rules:

Unimproved properties, railroads and utilities (but not buildings) may be sold to any player as a private transaction for any amount the owner can get.


That said you’re likely to hurt feelings if your friends are competitive.

Playing Monopoly is likely to hurt feelings. :-)
